# MVC, Browser return error: Website redirected you too many times When I browse a file on a specific restricted folder by web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, iis-8.5

I want restrict access of anonymous users to Music folder (in the root of my website). Then I put this code in **web.config** file **in the `Music` folder**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>           
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I tested this one too:

```
<allow users="*" />
<deny users="?" />
```

---

Also the **web.config** file of the website has the bellow config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      
      <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
      <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
</modules>

<rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<location path="~/Music">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers accessPolicy="Read" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

---

And this code is part of the **startup.cs**:

```
var loginPath= new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action(MVC.Account.Login());

appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString(loginPath),
    // Other Codes
}
```

Now, when i browse to `example.com/music/1.mp3` it return me to `/account/login` but when i login it show me the following error from the browser:

> WebsiteName redirected you too many times.
>
> net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

[image]

Also if i change the **authentication mode** to `none`, it show me a prompt like it (that i wont it!):
[image]

> **Note1:** I cleared the browser cookies but no success.

- **What is the reason of the redirect loop?**
- **How should do this work as safe without redirect loop?**

---

**Update:**

My project has a *Return to Url* mechanism in the login page. So when i browse `/Music/1.mp3` it redirect me to `/account/login?ReturnUrl=/Music/1.mp3`and after login base this mechanism it redirect me to `/Music/1.mp3` automatically. I think in this step I have not enough access permission to open `/Music/1.mp3` again! And it redirect me to login page again and this loop continue until i get `ERR_T_OOMANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set "authenticate mode" to none, as your web.config has a required login `<deny users="?" />`, then the request will send a login request to the browser, then it will ask you by the browser login form.

**What is the reason of the redirect loop?**

This error may occur for a lot of reasons. The most common is that login is redirecting to a folder that user cannot access even once it is logged-in.

For instance, Your music folder web.config is denying a logged user. Then it will redirect from the folder to the login, then login will authenticate, then it will send the user back to the folder. Once the folder is denying all users, then it will send back to login again, and bingo, here is your loop.

you must make sure that you're not denying logged-in users.

**How should do this work as safe without redirect loop?**

After redirect from login the server will deliver the .mp3 file required.

Please note that when using MVC you must be sure that the folders that you have in your project not always match the path that user type in URL. For MVC Core application those contents must be on wwwroot folder.

Comment: Yes and the question is: What is the reason of denying logged-in users in Music folder. There is not any location config in web.config file about Music folder.